# ls don't display correct color with bold in xterm

Tags: x11, ls, colors, xterm, xmonad

I use xmonad with xterm, seeing picture below. It displays color in xterm but ls cannot display correct color with bold font.

What is showing now:

[image]
[image]

My Xresources is a copy of solarized/xresources. Link to my file: [content in Xresoures](https://gitlab.com/Vonfry/dotfiles/raw/master/Xresources)

Comment: Multi-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624403/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `*boldColors: false` into .Xresources can solve this.